# setting textbox text equal to textbox text on a different form?

Tags: vb.net

is it possible in design mode to set the textbox text property to the text property of a textbox in a different form in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ApplicationSettings.PropertyBinding property of the text box to accomplish what you want.  If you sort the text box properties A-Z, it should be the first one in the list in parenthesis.  Just create a shared application value and it will apply to each control that binds to the value.

Comment: im sorry can u give me more specific instructions on how to accomplish this

Comment: Expand the (ApplicationSettings) property that displays when you select the text box.  It should be in the list that contains Name, Text, Width, etc.  Click the down arrow next to the Text property and click the New link.  Create a named property.